# I am having intents on bot for discord but showing error for intents?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am getting this error with doing `node .` in the terminal

```
my-dir\Discord-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (D:\Aarsh\Discord-Bot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (D:\Aarsh\Discord-Bot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Aarsh\Discord-Bot\index.js:2:13)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {`enter code here`
  [←[32mSymbol(code)←[39m]: ←[32m'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'←[39m
}
```

I don't know the reason why but still gets this error, I also have my bots intents on.
Please Help me

Thanks For Help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As transitioning from Discord.js version 12 to [Discord.js version 13](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable) you now have to define the [intents](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents) needed by your [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) to function.

You may define them like so:

```js
    const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Client({ intents: 32767 }); // justifies all intents
```

You may generate a suitable bitfield for the intents you need [here](https://ziad87.net/intents/).

Answer (score 0):

Since discord.js v13 you are required to specify the intents your client uses. You can read more about them [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents)

Comment: This could have been a comment

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.